# Navigation within ItemRenderer

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air

How can we navigate within an itemRenderer?

For example, in Views we use the View.navigator (ViewNavigator) to push and pop views, there is no such feature in ItemRenderer.

**Navigation within a View (Easy)**

```
<s:View>
<s:HGroup >
    <s:Button label="Questionnaire" click="navigator.pushView(view.QuestionnaireCategory1View)"/>
</s:HGroup>
```

**Navigation within a Item Renderer (Impossible?)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                autoDrawBackground="true" height="56">
    <s:HGroup>
        <s:Button text="Button" click="?????????"/>
    </s:HGroup>


</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use bubbling events to catch when the user interacts with an item renderer.

```
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <s:HGroup>
        <s:Button text="Button" click="dispatchEvent(new Event('buttonClicked', true));"/>
    </s:HGroup>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Then when do this with whatever is using your item renderer:

```
<DataGroup id="group" itemRenderer="YourItemRenderer" dataProvider="{someData}" creationComplete="group.addEventListener('buttonClick', someHandlerFunction);" />
```

And then within your handler function, do whatever action you wanted to do.  In this case, I'm adding the event listener on creation complete of the DataGroup, but you can add it to the creation complete event of the main container.  This way you keep your item renderer decoupled and reusable, as well as using proper software practices (data in, events out).

Comment: excellent but how do we know what was clicked? Ie if we have mutliple buttons in an item renderer

Comment: You can either change the event type to something more specific, or create a custom event class that can hold more data which can then be used later. It really depends what you're trying to do.  Make sure your events are descriptive to an action, not a component.  Right now I'm using 'buttonClicked', but it's not really appropriate since I didn't know what that button does/did.

Answer (score 1):

In when you create your itemRenderer

```
<comp:MyItemRenderer navigator="{navigator}"/>
```

In your itemRenderer (here call MyItemRenderer)

```
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                autoDrawBackground="true" height="56">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import spark.components.ViewNavigator;

        private var _navigator:ViewNavigator;

        public function set navigator(value:ViewNavigator):void
        {
            _navigator = value;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:HGroup>
    <s:Button label="Button" click="{_navigator.pushView(view.QuestionnaireCategory1View)}"/>
</s:HGroup>
```

Comment: Ye thats how I did it, seems abit rubbish you have to keep passing the navigator about though :( would of at least thought it would have been statically accessible!

Comment: That may solve the solution, but it's a horrible practice.  Plus, if you're not creating a factory for an 'item renderer', then it's not an item renderer, it's a component. -1